# No thread created despite success on return from pthread_create()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I have written quite a lot of threaded code on HP-UX and even SUSE and that works perfectly. But it does not work on Red Hat. This is my machine:

Linux version 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)

Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Release_Notes-7-en-US-7-2.el7.noarch

redhat-release-server-7.7-10.el7.x86_64

I wrote a simple test program, thr_ex.c:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



void *funny(void *);



void *funny(s)
void *s;

{ 
    int fd;


    fd = creat("/tmp/funny_func", 0600);

    write(fd, s, strlen((char *) s));

    close(fd);
}



int main()

{
    int                 return_value;
    pthread_t           thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t      thread_attr;


    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    return_value = pthread_create(&thread_id, &thread_attr, funny, (void *) "Here I am\n");

    printf("Return value == %d\n", return_value);
    printf("Thread id    == %hu\n", thread_id);

    exit(0);
} /* End main. */
```

Compiling, building:

gcc -pthread -s -o thr_ex thr_ex.c

Running:

./thr_ex

Return value == 0

Thread id    == 5888

But no file gets created under /tmp.
strace -f shows no creat() or write() ( except from the printf's in main () ).

However, strace -f do show, for example:
strace: Exit of unknown pid 64574 ignored

I have tried even simpler code where the thread only runs a printf() and a fflush(), with no thread attributes and no argument to the function. Still nothing happens.

Comment: Where did you find this example, with ancient K&R function argument definition?

Comment: As for your problem, you never wait for the thread to finish. Instead you terminate the process immediately after thread creation (which means it might not even have time to run).

Comment: @Anders  Insert pthread_exit( NULL ); before return.

Comment: To elaborate, when the process ends (with `exit(0)`) all threads of the process ends with it. To let detached threads (and the process itself) run in the "background" only exit the "main thread" (using `pthread_exit` instead of `exit`).

Comment: Alternatively, leave the second thread joinable, and join it before `exit()`ing the program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did not find an example. I like K&R C programming. I will try pthread_exit().

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought about that but I want to use detached threads.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I will try pthread_exit().

Answer (score 2):

Insert before the return statement or exit( 0 ) statement in main

```
pthread_exit( NULL );
```

Otherwise the created thread can have no time to be executed because the process will end.

Comment: To put it another way, the program has race conditions between everything executed by the second thread and the `exit(0)` executed by the main thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Exactly, thanks. I just thought the second thread would have time to execute at least a few times of all the tests I ran.